# Determine what caused scroll event to fire up

Tags: javascript, dom-events

It is known that `scroll` event could be fired up by using mouse-wheel, clicking on scrollbar arrows or dynamically with `window.scrollTo(left, top)` function.

Is it possible to determine what caused the `scroll` event to fire up? Whether it was user intervention or JS code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can determine what caused the scrolling. The scroll event only indicates that the window is scrolling, not *why* it's scrolling.

But perhaps you suspend the scroll event listener or set a flag before calling `window.scrollTo()` from your code. Here in Safari, if you use `scrollTo()`, the scroll event only fires once regardless of how much you scroll, so you could conceivably do something like this:

```
// somewhere in your code...
isCodedScrollEvent = true;
window.scrollTo(0, 200);

// elsewhere in your code...
function scrollListener(event) {
    if( isCodedScrollEvent ) {
         // event was caused by code, so handle it differently
         // and then flip the flag back to false, so the next
         // will be handled normally again
         isCodedScrollEvent = false;
    } else {
         // event was caused by user
    }
}
```

It ain't pretty, but it ought to work

Comment: used something like this recently, I can vouch, it actually works quite well. I was trying to detect when a scroll event was from a user in the middle of tweening a scroll. I was using greensock's `onUpdate()` timeline function and found that if I set a flag in that function, it would time well with the scroll listener. Then you just reset the flag. If a user interrupted the scroll, the flag would not be set and you can kill your animation...